# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload script - reset progress bar

Tags: jquery, file-upload, progress-bar, reset, blueimp

I searched my answer online but with no luck.
I have [posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-fileupload/uIFwW6gTjPo) on their support forum, no luck either.
I have also searched in their [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options), to try to find some info about setting up the progress bar, but found nothing useful.
Can someone point me in the right direction.
I need to be able to reset the progress to zero, between the two file uploads, and animate the bar again on the second file upload.
Thank You.

Comment: post your code, please

Answer (score 6):

you can set the progress bar width back to 0 (instead of 100%) in your `done` Callback:

```
done: function (e, data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width',0);
    }, 1500);
    ...
}
```

..I'm using setTimeout to give the bar some time to "transition" to its "done" state and remain there for a bit before receding back.

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer. Worked using jQuery File Upload Plugin Version 5.31 out of the box.

Comment: If you upload multiple files at once, the "done" callback will be invoked by each file.  The progress bar would then start fluctuating.

Comment: Thanks @dlg_ for the comment . It's been so long since I worked with this, but I wonder if there is a 'global done' or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to solve this issue, I have to say it works very well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileupload').click(function(){
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', 0);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').html('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use callback feature like this:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {
   $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width',0);
});
```

Also see [Callback Options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options)